# My bot gets very slow when reading a message

Tags: discord.js

I have a problem, I have 3 commands that are always active, which detect when spam, links, or flood occurs on a server, but when activated the bot gets very slow and takes a long time to execute a command, what can I do?

commands in the main file

```js
client.commands.get('spam').execute(message, keyv);
client.commands.get('links').execute(message, keyv);
client.commands.get('flood').execute(message, keyv);
```

spam.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
module.exports = {
    name: 'spam',
    description: 'detecta spam',
    execute(message, keyv) {
         (async () => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;       
    const serverid = message.guild.id;
    const channelid = message.channel.id;
    var affectbotsenadis = await keyv.get('spam' + "affectbots" + "enadis" + serverid);
    var delmsgenadis = await keyv.get('spam' + "delmsg" + "enadis" + serverid);
    var getsupsafeenadis = await keyv.get('supsafe' + "enadis" + serverid);  
    var getenadis = await keyv.get('spamprotection' + "enadis" + channelid + serverid);       
    if(message.content.includes("acaba") || message.content.includes("unio")) return;       
    else if(message.content.includes("unanse") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("Unanse") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("UNANSE") && message.content.includes("SERVER")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("Únanse") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("únanse") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("ÚNANSE") && message.content.includes("SERVER")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("une") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("Une") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("UNE") && message.content.includes("SERVER")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("una") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("Una") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("UNA") && message.content.includes("SERVER")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("unir") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("Unir") && message.content.includes("server")) avise(); 
    else if(message.content.includes("UNIR") && message.content.includes("SERVER")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("uniros") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("Uniros") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("UNIROS") && message.content.includes("SERVER")) avise(); 
    else if(message.content.includes("unios") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("Unios") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("UNIOS") && message.content.includes("SERVER")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("Unanse") && message.content.includes("serv")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("unanse") && message.content.includes("serv")) avise();      
    else if(message.content.includes("UNANSE") && message.content.includes("SERV")) avise(); 
    else if(message.content.includes("Unete") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();       
    else if(message.content.includes("unete") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("UNETE") && message.content.includes("SERVER")) avise();      
    else if(message.content.includes("ÚNETE") && message.content.includes("SERVER")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("Únete") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("únete") && message.content.includes("server")) avise();       

    else if(message.content.includes("Unanse") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("UNANSE") && message.content.includes("SERVIDOR")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("Únanse") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("únanse") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("ÚNANSE") && message.content.includes("SERVIDOR")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("une") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("Une") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("UNE") && message.content.includes("SERVIDOR")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("unir") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("Unir") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise(); 
    else if(message.content.includes("UNIR") && message.content.includes("SERVIDOR")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("uniros") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("Uniros") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();  
    else if(message.content.includes("UNIROS") && message.content.includes("SERVIDOR")) avise(); 
    else if(message.content.includes("unios") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("Unios") && message.content.includes("servidor")) avise();
    else if(message.content.includes("UNIOS") && message.content.includes("SERVIDOR")) avise();         



           function avise(){
             if(affectbotsenadis == "false"){
               if(message.author.bot) return;
             }
             if(getsupsafeenadis == "true"){
             if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return;  
             }
             if(getenadis == "disable") return;
               if(delmsgenadis == "true"){
                 message.delete();
               }
               else{
                 message.react("⚠")
               }
             const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
               .setDescription(message.author + ", Cuidado con ese spam")
             .setColor("RED")
             message.channel.send(embed)
             }

        })();

        },
};
```

links.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
module.exports = {
    name: 'links',
    description: 'molesta al bot',
    execute(message, keyv) {




    if(message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/')) avise2();  
    else if(message.content.includes("http://") && message.content.includes(".com")) avise2();
    else if(message.content.includes("https://") && message.content.includes(".com")) avise2();
    else if(message.content.includes("http://") && message.content.includes(".mx")) avise2();  
    else if(message.content.includes("https://") && message.content.includes(".mx")) avise2();         



           function avise2(){
                  (async () => {       
             const serverid = message.guild.id;
    const channelid = message.channel.id;
    let affectbotsenadis = await keyv.get('links' + "affectbots" + "enadis" + serverid);
    let delmsgenadis = await keyv.get('links' + "delmsg" + "enadis" + serverid);
    let getsupsafeenadis = await keyv.get('supsafe' + "enadis" + serverid);  
    let getenadis = await keyv.get('linksprotection' + "enadis" + channelid + serverid);       

             if(affectbotsenadis == "false"){
               if(message.author.bot) return;
             }
             if(getsupsafeenadis == "true"){
             if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return;  
             }
             if(getenadis == "disable") return;

               if(delmsgenadis == "true"){
                 message.delete();
               }
               else{
                 message.react("⚠")
               }

             const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
               .setDescription(message.author + ", Cuidado con ese link")
             .setColor("RED")
             message.channel.send(embed)
              })();
             }



        },
};
```

flood.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const  client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports = {
    name: 'flood',
    description: 'Ping!',
    execute(message, keyv){
     (async () => {
       if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content.length >= 450){
    const serverid = message.guild.id;
    const channelid = message.channel.id;
    var getenadis = await keyv.get('floodprotection' + "enadis" + channelid + serverid);
    if(getenadis == "disable") return;
      message.react("⚠")
   const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription(message.author + ", Cuidado con ese flood")
      .setColor("RED")
      message.channel.send(embed)
    }
        })();
    },
};
```

when I remove those commands from the code, the bot is normal again, but when you put them back, it gets slow again, and it takes about 3 seconds to execute a command, what is wrong or what can I do?

Comment: Its probably because you have too much of else ifs you can make it all that includes into 4 by using [`.toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: For links you can use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: I already decreased it, but it's still slow

Comment: Using [`switch`/`case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) rather than `if` statements and comparing the string case-**in**sensitively should provide better performance.

Comment: i don't know how to use switch / case in my code

Comment: Check out the hyperlinked documentation with plenty of examples and explanations. Aim to learn rather than copy and paste.